# Seeing Google Compute Engine API requests but I am only using Cloud DNS

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using Google Cloud Platform for the first time. I set up some Google Cloud DNS zones, and when I look at my API Manager Dashboard I see API requests for both Cloud DNS and Compute Engine.

Where are the Compute Engine API requests coming from? I don't have any Compute Engine instances. Shouldn't I only see Cloud DNS requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have GCE API enabled in your project its expected to see some requests. These requests are for creating and updating GCE resources e.g. GCE networks, firewall rules etc. You can view the GCE resource information through Cloud console->Compute Engine->Quotas page. You will not be charged for these requests.